# TMGMT translations are not accepted when there is a pending revision in the default translation

Tags: paragraphs

Can someone please help with TMGMT (8.x-1.14) and Paragraphs (8.x-1.15) modules working together in Drupal 9.4.8 setup.

There is a content type having a Paragraph entity reference revision field. Consider a node is already published. I made a change to the node and Requested for a translation, say JP. I worked on the translation and got it reviewed. Remember that the Original language content is still in Draft state. If I keep the "Translation state" as Draft too and click on "Save as completed", I get an error message "This translation cannot be accepted as there is a pending revision in the default translation."

If I do the same steps with a node of content type which doesn't have a paragraph field, it goes through perfectly.

My ultimate aim is that when the Original language content is changed, users should be able to create and publish all the translations at once and without having to Publish the EN content first and then the rest.

Has anyone faced this issue earlier?

Comment: Hello, can someone please help here.